# How can set a select query to a variable and use it in another select query in mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have 10 plus select queries. In all the queries I need to use a common sub query. So for reusability, I thought of putting sub query in a variable and use it in other select queries.
Below is the sample code I'm trying but it is not working.

```
declare querySelect varchar(1000);
set querySelect="SELECT Id from orgs where orgType =5";

select * from organisation where Id in (select querySelect);
```

Comment: Why do you have 10 queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option here would be to create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW orgView AS
SELECT Id FROM orgs WHERE orgType = 5;
```

Then select from this view in your subsequent queries, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM organisation WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM orgView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `prepare statement`

```
set @querySelect="SELECT Id from orgs where orgType =5";
SET @sql = CONCAT("select * from organisation where Id in ( ",@querySelect," )");
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```